# How comparate 2 sql bash script

Tags: linux, bash, script, sql

I've got 2 SQL files, 1 of them, is a SQLite tranformed data base and the other, is a SQL file to make a secure copy, the problem, I dont know how take this 2 files and comparate them and make the secure save, the minimal changes needed to make it the same as the sqlite transformed, its for a make a big database.
My current script

```
#!/bin/bash
#test
#Nombre de los ficheros
sdb=prueba; #Ubicacion del fichero el cual empezaremos la conversion
mysql=SQLprueba; #Nombre del fichero el cual se creara y a posterior se utilizara
script=sqlite3-to-mysql.py #Ubicacion del fichero script.py para conversion
#Login de la base de datos
user=root;
paswd=new_password;

#Almacenador de comandos 
hora_fichero=`ls -l | grep $sdb | cut -d" " -f10 |tr -d ":"`
hora_local=date | cut -d" " -f5 | cut -d":" -f1-2 | tr -d ":"
minutos=5
comandosql=`sqlite3 $sdb .dump> $mysql.sql` #convierte el sqlite en sql
comandomysql= ./$script $mysql.sql >$mysql.mysql #Convierte el sql en mysql
#Inicio del programa 
echo "Convertidor de ficheros automatizado"
if [ "$hora_local-$hora_fichero -lt 5"  ]; then #Realiza la copia de seguridad porque han pasado mas de x segundos
    echo "Vamos a proceder"
    if [ -f $sdb ]; then #Combrueba que el fichero exista por si las moscas
        if [ -f $mysql ]; then #Comprueba que no exista un .mysql y lo borra por si las moscas
            rm $mysql.sql
            echo "el fichero existe, transformando"
            $comandosql
            $comandomysql
        else
            echo "el fichero existe, transformando"
            $comandosql
            $comandomysql
        fi
    else
        echo "el fichero a transformar es inexistente"
    fi
else
    echo "No hay nada a salvar" #No es necesario  copia, no ha habido nada modificado en estos 5 m
fi
```

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code. Especially with (user subjective) terrible color schemes. As for comparing two files: `diff`? I don't really get what you're trying to achieve assuming you have two files that just contain SQL statements?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve. I guess the scenario is like:

- There is a large text file `A`.
- There is a large text file `B` which shares most lines with `A`, there are differences though.
- You want to make backup of all the information but you don't want to copy/transmit/store both files as they are. Instead your idea is to store `A` *and* the minimal information enough to reproduce `B` from `A`.

If so, then `diff` and `patch` are the tools you need.

---

The basic procedure is quite straightforward. Assuming you have `A` and `B` (and no file named `A2B.patch` because it will be overwritten) in your current directory, run:

```
diff A B > A2B.patch
```

Then if you have `A` and `A2B.patch` (and no `B`), you can recreate `B` with:

```
patch -o B A A2B.patch
```

Note: "`A2B.patch`" is just an arbitrary name I chose; it can be "`foo`".

---

**The tools work with lines. The fewer common lines you have, the less effective this solution will be.**

If I interpret your script right, your `B` is the output of `sqlite3-to-mysql.py A`. I don't know what `sqlite3-to-mysql.py` does exactly, nor I'm deep enough into SQL to reliably guess. If it changes most lines of `A` to create `B` then my solution will be useless. I mean: it should still work but `patch` will be larger than `B` so it will miss the point.

Maybe just run `diff A B > patch` once and check if `patch` is small enough for your purpose.

Study [`man 1 patch`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1p/patch/) and [`man 1 diff`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1p/diff/) to learn more. I was also consulting [this site](https://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux/introduction-using-diff-and-patch/) while writing my answer.

Comment: Yes, the file B its a output from a SQLite to SQL, with this 2 files i need comparate them and the B output make a diff